# What is the music played during the fight between Juuzou and the Owl in episode 11 of Tokyo Ghoul Root A?

Tags: music, tokyo-ghoul

What is the name of the music played at 11:50 in Tokyo Ghoul Root A, episode 11 when Juuzou and the other Ghoul investigators are fighting the Owl? I like that pretty much.

Answer (score 0):

What I've found out is it's called "Tokyo Ghoul - Yukata Yamada"